# How to order by category as well as price category will come multiple times in result

Tags: php, mysql

I have on list page in that i need to display data order by category as well as price. I know I can use multiple orderby but in my list the same category will come multiple times.

So I need to display all category order by alphabetically as well as price.

For example:

```
Category       Price
---------      ------
Apple          10
Apple          20
Apple          30
Banana         05
Banana         10
Banana         20
Coconuts       10
Coconuts       50
```

**Result should be like above table. If i use multiple order by it is displaying lowest to highest price.**

So the same category must be coming  together with order by price.

Hope all can understand.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Please give us your query.

Answer (score 1):

This should do.

```
 SELECT .. .. ORDER BY Category ASC, Price ASC;
```